# WSGI error using datapsuher in ckan

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi, ckan

I'm installing the datapusher, CKAN extension. The CKAN installation (version 2.4.1) is in source mode, and when I test the datapusher installation in develop environment mode everything is ok. However, when installed in production mode (for this I have installed Apache 4.4.17 from source and mod_wsgi 4.4.21 from source), when testing the datapusher using the curl command to call localhost:8800, it fails and returns this error:

```
[Mon Nov 16 12:41:03.697713 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 1709] [client 10.178.174.65:56283] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'datapusher': /xxxxxx/opendata/ckan/datapusher.wsgi, referer: http://XXXXXXXXXX:8800/
```

I was reading the mod_wsgi documentation and testing including the parameter WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} and recompiling  specifing the python location, and I reviewed that in datapusher.wsgi and datapusher_settings.py the activate_this.py location are correct.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have Apache and mod-wsgi installed from source?

Comment: Own client prefer to use this newest versions because that solve some issues.
I tried to reproduce the error in other environment with this versions of apache and mod_wsgi and the error don't appeared.

Comment: My suspicion is that some configuration option is off from normal defaults in your compiled combo of apache and mod_wsgi.